# Unable to click on a checkbox as its element is not aligned correctly using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xadN9.png)URL:- https://ksrtc.in/oprs-web/login/show.do
I have a checkbox before Terms and Conditions link. I need to click on it but since its misaligned i am unable to click on it.

I have tried using various locators, synchronizations but nothing works. I even tried using actions class. I thought its overlapped so i got terms and conditions link in a webelement and then i performed search on it to get the checkbox, but in vain.
Is it possible to interact with such elements.
Note:- Whatever locator i use i have searched them in automated browser window that opens up while running the test case and i have searched there and it does highlight the element.

Comment: What does this have to do with `java` and `selenium-webdriver`? Please tag your question appropriately

Comment: I have logged in to stack overflow for the first time yesterday to ask a question. Since i was trying to automate the test case using selenium webdriver with java, i put those tags. If these are incorrect could you please let me know what tags should they be. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Your question sounds like it is more about html and css, but if you are trying to automate it then your tags are fine. The issue is your question is not clear.

Comment: You need to provide a minimum reproducable example of the code and provide more details if you want help with your question. See [How to Ask and Answer](https://stackoverflow.co/teams/resources/how-to-ask-and-answer/) for more information on how to better structure your question.

Answer (score 2):

Locate the element that represents the checkbox (in front of the "Terms and Conditions" label) instead of the actual checkbox having the id #TermsConditions.custom-control-input.

When you manually tick this checkbox , if you are able to submit the form, then there may be a javascript function being called to tick the actual misaligned checkbox (#TermsConditions.custom-control-input). If this is the case, try calling the same function.

However, when ticking the checkbox if you are unable to submit the form because you didn't agree to the T&C (assuming this will be indicated in red font/ highlighted in red/ other relevant symbol), then this may be a bug.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqNVT.png) is the element that represents the checkbox for clarification.